# How do I do a callback with dygraph range selector

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am displaying data on the same page as my graph and if a user uses the range selector, I want a callback that will allow me to only show the data points in that range. Is this possible? Maybe another callback that can be used such as first and last points? Does such a thing exist? I could not find it in the manual.

Comment: Do `zoomCallback` or `drawCallback` do what you want?

Comment: I'll try those. thanks Dan.

Comment: Can you add a reply instead of a comment so i can select it as the right one? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`zoomCallback`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#zoomCallback) and [`drawCallback`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#drawCallback).